# Keep google chrome extension ContentScripts working while javascript is blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I currently started fiddling with google chrome extensions. My extension currently does inject some javascript into every website, which creates a sidebar with some functions (which functions doesn't really matter though). Everything works while javascript is enabled for those websites, but stops working when it's blocked. I inject the code via chrome.tabs.executeScript and it clearly loads on every pages startup (as the sidebar is created) but it's just a simple div at this time (so as I said, none of the functions keeps working). I tried to inject a  tag before, which simply does nothing (so no sidebar is created) when javascript is blocked.. so there clearly is a difference, but neither works for me.

As far as I understood how contentScripts works, they should run in an isolated world and therefore shouldn't be effected by the sites javascript options (as every other part of the extension -background pages and such- still keeps working). I searched the web for answers but couldn't find anything (well I found one bug report which was closed without being properly answered) on this issue. Does anybody know how to keep injected code running while the site's javascript gets blocked (like special permissions or such) or do I have to abandon my idea? Thanks in advance!

EditII: In the meantime I tested some contentscripts and well, yes some of them continue working even if javascript is turned off. As I initially stated my script also is execute at first, but won't maintain it's functionality. For a better understanding a really slim version of what should be going on. Is there a way to keep those functions running or is it hopeless because they are injected too deep into the site?

Manifest.json

```
{
"name" : "Example",
"version" : "1.0.1",
"description" : "Creates a sidebar, which looses dragable() function when javascript is turned off",

"permissions" : [ "tabs" ],

"content_scripts" : [
  {
    "matches" : [ "http://*/*" ],
    "js" : [  "jquery.js", "jquery-ui.js", "contentscript.js" ],
    "run_at" : "document_end",
    "all_frames" : true
  }
],
"manifest_version": 2
 }
```

contentscript:

```
var sidebar;

sidebar = $("<div id='example_sidebar'></div>");
sidebar.css({
  'position': 'fixed',
  'right': '0px',
  'top': '200px',
  'z-index': 9999,
  'width': '70px',
  'height': '140px',
   'background-color': 'blue'  // Confirm it shows up
 });
$('body').append(sidebar);

$(function() {
  $( "#example_sidebar" ).draggable();
});

 $("#example_sidebar")
.on( "mouseenter", function() {
  console.log('entered the div');
})
.on( "mouseleave", function() {
 console.log('left the div'); 
});

$('#example_sidebar').on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked the div');});
```

Comment: Without testing, I would also expect content scripts to run even if JS is disabled for the page. Does your content script (or script injected with `executeScript`) rely on inserting a `<script>` tag into the DOM? I *would* expect that to fail, if you needed the `<script>` to be evaluated in the context of the actual page.

Comment: Although executeScript doesn't visibly add a <script> tag I guess it could be the case background wise. As I stated, the interessting fact is that executeScript nevertheless creates the div even if javascript is blocked, it simply lacks the functions. I edited the start post with a simple example that has the same problems as my extension though.

Comment: Edited the original post another time with a slim version of what should actually going on.

Comment: If javascript is disabled on the page could chrome be stopping the events from firing?  Can you add a simple click handler that logs to the console?

Comment: Edited the post again with the requested handler. As you thought, chrome stops the events from firing and my sidebar is treated as a normal div without any functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this: There currently is no way in keeping functions of a contentScript running while JavaScript is disabled. Probably this feature will never be implemented, but who knows. You are still able to execute some code though e.g. DOM Manipulation is still possible, hence the menu I wanted to inject was still displayed.